# Hiding filters for a playa field

Tags: playa

Is there a way to hide the filters for a Playa field that has is set to allow multiple entries? This is being used in a safecracker form and I don't want users to see statuses, categories, member groups etc - just a simple drag and drop list that shows entries from A-Z.

Thanks

Comment: Did you see [this answer](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5710/22) to a similar question?  It applies to the CP, but might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alex Kendrick - I don't know why I didn't think of hiding the plus/minus buttons with the site theme's CSS: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5710/22